# The component 'LiveCharts.Wpf.DefaultLegend' does not have a resource identified by the URL '/LiveCharts.Wpf;component/defaultlegend.xaml'

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, livecharts

I have been programming on a winforms project for about a month days. Recently one of the form designers always show an error page.

When the project is just loaded on VS, there's no error. After I do some modification then rebuild it will show the error page of: [image]

> The component 'LiveCharts.Wpf.DefaultLegend' does not have a resource identified by the URL '/LiveCharts.Wpf;component/defaultlegend.xaml'.

and the call stack shows:

```
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
at LiveCharts.Wpf.DefaultLegend.InitializeComponent() in c:\Users\btord\Documents\Projects\LiveCharts\WpfView\DefaultLegend.xaml:line 1
at LiveCharts.Wpf.Charts.Base.Chart..ctor() in c:\Users\btord\Documents\Projects\LiveCharts\WpfView\Charts\Base\Chart.cs:line 82
at LiveCharts.Wpf.CartesianChart..ctor() in c:\Users\btord\Documents\Projects\LiveCharts\WpfView\CartesianChart.cs:line 40
at LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart..ctor() in c:\Users\btord\Documents\Projects\LiveCharts\WinFormsView\CartesianChart.cs:line 46
at Controls.Chart.MyChart.InitializeComponent()
at Controls.Chart.MyChart..ctor()
```

I checked the path but found no 'c:\Users\btord' directory and a few days ago I moved my Documents directory to D driver.

Sometimes after I build on release it will show another error page of:

[image]

> Could not load file or assembly 'LiveCharts.WinForms, Version=0.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0bc1f845d1ebb8df' or one of its dependencies.

And there's no error in source code of the designer at all, neither when building. The execute file can run healthily.

Comment: `btord` is the creator of this open source project, this information is built into the assemblies so you see this folder in the stack trace.

Comment: Try to uninstall and then reinstall the package `LiveCharts.WinForms` from nuget package manager, and rebuild the solution. It looks like one of the dependencies is missing somehow.

Comment: @kennyzx Thank you the problem seems to be solved, hope it won't occur again.

Comment: In addition, the package of LiveCharts.Wpf also needs to be reinstall. I choosed reinstalling all the LiveCharts packages.

Comment: OK. This is because the WinForms version uses WPF advanced rendering system, so you are actually running the WPF package with a wrapper to create a Windows Forms user control class, therefore you need 3 name spaces. Quoted from [this page](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/wf/Install)

Comment: @kennyzx I'm sorry but the problem occurred again. It seems that reinstalling is useless.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to commonly happen when multiple copies of live charts dll's are present in a solution build.
For me it was used both in the main executable and a plugin class library building in a sub folder.  The effect is two copies of the Live Charts dll's in different folders which it doesn't like.

**Packages.config**

If using a packages.config file to handle references you can set the LiveCharts references to "CopyLocal"=false for the extra projects.  This stops multiple copies of the dll's being included the build.  It will happily use the copy loaded in the main project.

**Package References**

Sadly there isn't an option to not copy the files when using the newer style package references.
Removing extra copies post build seems the easiest workaround I've found.

In Project Properties, Build events page, post build event command line box add

`del $(TargetDir)LiveCharts.*`

$(TargetDir) is your projects output path.